# Kotlin invoke companion function with reflection

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. Facing an issue with reflection and generics. Below is my code.

```
abstract class Action {
  fun sleep(body: Person.() -> Unit){
    var p = Person("a");
    p.body()
    println(p.name + " is zzzzzzz...")
  }
}

class Person(var name:String =""){
  companion object:Action();
}

inline fun <reified T> test(){
  val companionObject = T::class.companionObject
  if (companionObject != null) {
    println(companionObject.javaObjectType)
    val functionEx = companionObject.functions.filter { it.name.equals("sleep") }.first()
    // How to invoke functionEx with block and "this"
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  Person.sleep {
    this.name = "abc"
  }
  test<Person>()
}
```

I want to invoke the `sleep` function through `functionEx` with the same block code which is in the main. I am struggling with the `this` operator.

I am using some API and have emulated the problem through `Action` and `Person`. So can't change their implementation. Its just the `test` function which is under my control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
inline fun <reified T> test() {
    val companionObject = T::class.companionObject
    if (companionObject != null) {
        val body: Person.() -> Unit = { println("body called on $name!") }
        val companionInstance = T::class.companionObjectInstance
        val functionEx = companionObject.functions.first { it.name.equals("sleep") }
        functionEx.call(companionInstance, body)
    }
}
```

To call the function using [`call(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/call.html#call), you need to pass the companion object instance as the first argument (which stands for the `sleep` function's receiver) and an instance of the [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) `Person.() -> Unit` as the second one.

Note that [`companionObject`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/companion-object.html) returns not the companion object instance but its `KClass`. To get the instance, use [`companionObjectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/companion-object-instance.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

hotkey's answer is fine when `T` is reified, ie the type is known at compilation time. When it is not known, because it's coming from Java's class, it is needed to first convert the class instance to a kotlin's `KClass`.

```
inline fun test(c: Class<*>) {
    val kotlinClass = c.kotlin
    val companionObject = kotlinClass.companionObject
    if (companionObject != null) {
        val body: Person.() -> Unit = { println("body called on $name!") }
        val companionInstance = kotlinClass.companionObjectInstance
        val functionEx = companionObject.functions.first { it.name.equals("sleep") }
        functionEx.call(companionInstance, body)
    }
}
```